# WPF grouped RadioButton with tabs inconsistent

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button

I have a number of `RadioButton` controls on different tabs of a WPF `TabControl`, with the same `GroupName` set (I'm aware that "parent panel" gives a scope when not specifying group name, the example is simplified). What I am observing is that sometimes these radio buttons behave as one group, yet sometimes they behave as distinct groups.

Example:

```
<TabControl>
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton GroupName="groupA" Content="11" />
        <RadioButton GroupName="groupA" Content="12" IsChecked="True" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton GroupName="groupA" Content="21" />
        <RadioButton GroupName="groupA" Content="22" IsChecked="True" />
    </StackPanel>
</TabControl>
```

In this case when the control is loaded, only one of the 4 buttons will be checked (the one on the 2nd tab which is not initially visible). However, when interactively clicking on any radio button, each tab will behave as a separate group.

Furthermore, if I programmatically add an additional tab with the same contents (one of the `StackPanel`s above), it will initially be selected and behave as a separate group, yet if I add 2 or more such tabs, only the last added one will get a selected item, as if all are part of the same group.

Why does the scope sometimes seem shared between tabs, but usually not? Is this to do with when the control is first added to the visual tree?